# wrong URL configuration/pattern in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django template, to call url for a link this is what I have done

```
{% for url in request.session.url %}
    <a href="{{url.linkfield}}" > 
        {{url.name}}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

With the above when I load the page the links comes out very well as expected.

```
e.g. www.url.com/ for home
     www.url.com/staff/firstpage for firstpage
     www.url.com/staff/secondpage for secondpage etc
```

But when I click on any of the links it would extend the link of the existing page e.g. clicking on firstpage with

link [www.url.com/staff/firstpage](http://www.url.com/staff/firstpage) result turns out to be

```
e.g. www.url.com/staff/firstpage for home
     www.url.com/staff/firstpage/firstpage for firstpage
     www.url.com/staff/firstpage/secondpage for secondpage etc
```

This is my url.py

```
app_name="application_name"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^staff/",include('application_name.staff_url', namespace='staff')),
    url(r"^customer/",include('application_name.customer_url', namespace='customer')),
]
```

my staff_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="staff"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^customers/",views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r"^orders/$", views.orders, name='orders'),
    url(r"^payments/$", views.payments, name='payments'),
]
```

but when I use {% url %} i.e. instead of `{{linkfield}}` i am using `{% url url.linkfield %}`
it is producing error in the console i.e.

```
  raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
dango.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'whatever_linkname' not found. 'whatever_linkname' is not
```

a valid view function or pattern name.

This is my url.py

```
app_name="application_name"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^staff/",include('application_name.staff_url', namespace='staff')),
    url(r"^customer/",include('application_name.customer_url', namespace='customer')),
]
```

my staff_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="staff"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^customers/",views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r"^orders/$", views.orders, name='orders'),
    url(r"^payments/$", views.payments, name='payments'),
]
```

my customer_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="customer"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^items/",views.items, name='items'),
    url(r"^checkout/$", views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    url(r"^make_payment/$", views.make_payment, name='make_payment'),
]
```

staf url would be `staff/orders` or `staff/payments`
customer urls would be `customer/items` or `customer/checkout` etc

Please what can i do

Answer (score 2):

This is how u can do it: `<a href="{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}"></a>`
In your case for example:  `<a href="{% url 'customer:items' %}"></a>`

- If you don't have an app_name u don't need to write it.

Comment: if you notice my application is multi level application i.e. application_name->customer->items. I tried that  it was  not giving me a desired result

Comment: I have tried {% url application_name:customer:items %} it was producing error

Comment: First arg is not the app name its the app_name that u set in your urls.py. and you cant pass 3 args it takes 1 or 2 args.